# Convergence or divergence of $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \left [ \cos(\frac {1} {k^{2}})-\cos(\frac {1} {(k+1)^{2}}) \right ]$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am working on a two part question. It asks me to determine whether two different infinite series are divergent or convergent. Here are the two infinite series:

> (a) $\sum _{i=1}^{\infty} \cos(\frac {1} {i^{2}})$
>
> (b) $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty} \left [ \cos(\frac {1} {k^{2}})-\cos(\frac {1} {(k+1)^{2}}) \right ]$

For part (a) I have determined it is divergent by finding $\lim_{i \to \infty} cos(\frac {1} {i^{2}})=1$, which shows that the series must be divergent. For part (b) I've found that both terms of the series approach 1 as $k \to \infty$. This means each term is divergent on its own. This doesn't tell me whether the series is convergent or divergent, it just tells me that the series *could* be convergent, because $\lim_{k \to \infty}a_{k}=0$. I am wondering what I can do to get a proper answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For part $(b)$ write down the the $N$th partial sum and notice that it is telescoping, i.e. $$\sum_{k=1}^N\big[(\cos(\frac{1}{k^2}) - \cos\big(\frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\big)\big] = \cos(1) -\cos\big(\frac{1}{(N+1)^2}\big)$$

Now the series is just the limit of the $N$th partial sum as $N$ goes to infinity, and thus the sum is $$ \lim_{N\to \infty} \big[\cos(1) -\cos\big(\frac{1}{(N+1)^2}\big)\big] = \cos(1) -\cos(0) = \cos(1) - 1$$

Comment: Thank you. I know for the future that if I'm stuck I should at least write out some of the first terms. I would have noticed that it was telescoping!

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(a)-\cos(b)=-2\sin(\dfrac{(a+b)}{2})\sin(\dfrac{(a-b)}{2})$, maybe what you need is this.